# In C++, is it bad practice to use a parameter pack as an initializer list?

Tags: c++, class, variadic-templates, parameter-expansion

I am currently experimenting with variadic templates, as I am trying to use a variadic class template for a project I am working on. I want the class to accept a list of integers which will be used to create other elements of the class. Initially, I was using a template constructor function to take an array of integers. However, I ran into problems linking the code. I figured out an alternate way of solving my problem using a variadic class template to take the list of integers, but I am curious if this code is considered bad c++ (I haven't written C++ in a while and this feels very hacky). Anyway, here is the test code I have written, which compiles and works as expected:

```
template<int...structure>
class testClass{

public:
testClass(){
      std::size_t size = sizeof...(structure);
      std::cout << size << '\n';
      int arr[]{ structure... };
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
          std::cout << arr[i] << '\n';
   }


};

int main() {
   testClass<1, 2, 3> c;
}
```

As expected, the code outputs:

```
3
1
2
3
```

Is there anything wrong with this solution? I have been searching online and no one seems to be using variadic templates in this way.

Thanks in advance for the input.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with that class?

Comment: When the constructor takes an array parameter, it is a run-time parameter. In your example it is a compile-time one. These are orthogonal in many cases.

Comment: @Evg not necessarily if the ctor is constexpr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong or hacky with your solution, it is just a trade off.  With your solution, you immediately initialize the array so it has the best performance.  With the `std::initializer_list` solutions they have to default the members of the array and then copy which is more work.

On the flip side that means you can only construct your object at compile time, while the `std::initializer_list`   version can be initialized at run time.

Another issue is storing them in a container.  You can't store different `testClass`'s in a `std::vector` since different template parameters mean they are different type and vector only stores a single element type. If you took a `std::initializer_list` then `testClass` wouldn't be a template and you can store different ones in the same `vector`.

Answer (score 3):

The only problem there is is that a pack can be empty, but not arrays. So in your example, `testClass<> c;` would not compile.

Either specialize your class so only instantiations with a non zero amount of parameters are defined or provide a placeholder element in the array:

```
int arr[]{ 0, structure... };
```

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you want.

> I want the class to accept a list of integers which will be used to create other elements of the class

You do not have one class that accepts a list of integers. What you have is a template that can be instantiated with a list of integers. That is a big difference. If you instantiate the template with different integers you get a different type. For example `testClass<1,2>` and `testClass<1,2,3>` are two different types that have little in common (actually nothing but being instantiations of the same template). If this is what you want your approach is ok.